# Where is the line of code in the Adafruit implementation of the PCA9685 PWM driver that writes to I2C?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, adafruit-circuitpython

Looking at the [source of the PCA9685 python lib](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685/blob/main/adafruit_pca9685.py#L134) I do see that an instance of `I2C` is passed in with var name `i2c_bus` to create an instance of the
`PCA9685` class. The `i2c_bus` variable is used to create an instance of `I2CDevice` ([source code of I2CDevice](https://github.com/adafruit/glitterpos/blob/59697a7a935ba2e117c4cfad323557cbb78db810/lib/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py)). But then I am lost. At some point this PWM driver should call [the write method](https://github.com/adafruit/glitterpos/blob/59697a7a935ba2e117c4cfad323557cbb78db810/lib/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py#L88) of the `I2CDevice` class I suppose. But this never happens! (FAFAIK). I also checked the `PWMChannel` class and `PCAChannels` class but neither do something related with i2c. Then I checked the [pca9685_simpletest.py](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685/blob/main/examples/pca9685_simpletest.py#L24) file and saw the following code:

```
# Set the PWM duty cycle for channel zero to 50%. duty_cycle is 16 bits to match other PWM objects
# but the PCA9685 will only actually give 12 bits of resolution.
pca.channels[0].duty_cycle = 0x7FFF
```

This should definitely cause some IO to happen on the I2C bus. But, no `write` method to some i2c bus or device there! It almost looks like [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) to me.

I have been looking certainly for an hour now, I must overlook something.

What is the mechanism of the PCA9685 class to write the data to the I2C bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `UnaryStruct` and `StructArray` classes.  Those are imported from `adafruit_register.i2c_struct` and `adafruit_register.i2c_struct_array`.  When you write to an object of class `UnaryStruct`, it generate an I2C write of a single byte.  When you write to `StructArray`, it generates a larger I2C write.

Pretty clever, but it does hide the implementation.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim! I did notice those where Adafruit specific thingies. I guess I was staring blind. Thanks so much!

Comment: Fun fact: I came to ditch the pi hat and use 2 separate DRV8825 drivers instead (simple GPIO based) so each motor can drive at a different speed (using 2 threads with each its own sleep). Driving the motors at different speeds using a single I2C would only be possible if the difference in sleep time between the motors are a multitude of one another.